# "Webview is blinking" issue on click on the Ipad device

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, svg

In the ipad application I have use Webview. the javascript code is performing action on clicking. With performing some action it is also blinking the webview. Here is the code

```
document.getElementById("layout").onclick=function(e){..some code..}
```

It is still blinking when I have commented all the code inside this function and return false. Please suggest.

Comment: Please add some code ,it will give light on what exactly you are doing

Comment: I would suggest why not use Touch events instead of click events, Since Touch events are efficient and fast on touch devices.

Comment: This bug depends entirely on what's inside of `{..some code..}`, please post it.

Comment: Thanks ameya rote, the touch resolve this. This was really due to click.